# Run AndroidTest on Android Emulator In Docker

Tags: android, docker, android-emulator, continuous-integration

I saw some links and posts about running AndroidTest in Docker. Like:

https://dzone.com/articles/running-android-tests-in-docker

https://github.com/ksoichiro/android-tests/tree/master/docker-emulator

And some more. However, they all seem inappropriate for AndroidTest in CI, since they require an actual VM, or simply they are too old.

I tried the following lines Docker Image (Partial):

```
RUN /opt/adk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "emulator" "build-tools;${BUILD_TOOLS}" "platforms;${ANDROID_PLATFORM}" "system-images;${ANDROID_PLATFORM};google_apis;armeabi-v7a" \
    && echo no | /opt/adk/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd -n "Android" -k "system-images;${ANDROID_PLATFORM};google_apis;armeabi-v7a" \
```

And then I run the emulator using:

```
/opt/adk/emulator/emulator @Android -writable-system -nocache -no-snapstorage &
```

However, when trying to run `connectedAndroidTest` there were some weird exceptions, like:
`Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unknown failure: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?`

Or, if I try to manually install the test APK, and run `am instrument`:
`android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?`

So my question: Is anyone is running AndroidTest on emulator as part of the CI on docker? Means, an image that you just need to mount your project and run `gradle connectedAndroidTest`, and everything works? Is there a working example for that?

Comment: Our CI runs on AWS. The solution we wanted to investigate, if someone interested, is to use Genymotion AWS image, and run the androidTest on it. (https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Genymobile-Inc-Genymotion-Cloud-Android-60-marshma/B01MREUQPU)

Answer (score 1):

I run AndroidTest on emulator as part of the CI on docker using this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/chrisss404/android-emulator

The problem you might encounter is that hardware acceleration is not available on your host because of missing nested KVM (just a guess, but that was the problem I was facing). In this case you have to use software rendering, which can take a significant amount of time.

With software rendering, the startup takes about 40 minutes until the emulator is usable (on my host). However, then you can run the instrumentation tests as usual in an acceptable timeframe.

Comment: Thanks! Are you running it locally or on AWS? Sounds like the docker is always live, and you do not initiate it during the CI, right?

Comment: I am not running it locally or on AWS, but on a VPS from hetzner (CX21). Yes you are right, the container is always running and not initiated during the CI build job.

Comment: @ChristianHofer: My container auto-exit within 30 seconds on mac. Do you mean, i should try running container again after 40 minutes?